# Smart vertical align for input labels, on a responsive layout

Tags: responsive-design, vertical-alignment, liquid-layout

I have the classic form with labels on left and input field on the right.
The site is responsive and liquid, so the labels content could span in two lines instead of one when there is not enough space.

This is the basic markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

At this point **I need the "labels on two-lines" to be vertically centered just like the others**.
This would be quite easy using a table, but I'm trying to have the site tables-free while avoiding JS for layout purposes.

Also, the site is required to work with IE8, so it is not possible to use some cool CSS3 property.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Not 100% sure I understand. Are you saying that you want the labels to appear above the input field when viewing it in responsive mode. And, it should cater for more than one line but be centred vertically?

Comment: No, always with the same layout with the labels on the left, but with the text in two rows to take less space.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/ You'd have to do one of the IE fixes towards the bottom

Comment: You don't need to worry about < IE8, unless you are using something like respond.js because it probably won't get that small to force labels to two lines.